# Remove Validation Rules Row by Row from Sheet Based on Column G Value

Tags: excel

Hy Experts, I am using an excel sheet that has multiple columns. Every column has validation rules. I want to remove these validation rules upon selecting any row in the entire sheet. When I select the row then I will put the value in G from drop down menu. on the basis of column G value the entire row validation rules should be cleared. The sheet looks like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0CFG.png)

The code that I am using is as under.

```
Sub RemoveDV()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Cells.Validation.Delete
    Next ws
    MsgBox ("All Validation Rules has been removed successfully")

End Sub
```

it  working fine but it delete the entire worksheet. But I want to delete the validation only row that I am working on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print Target.Address
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Value = "The value that will trigger the validation clearing" Then
            Target.EntireRow.Validation.Delete
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

This will trigger anytime you change a value in column "G" of the specified sheet and if the new value = the text you want.

**EDIT:**

Let say you store your values (values that will trigger the script) in a range on the same page you can adapt following code to your needs:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Arr: Arr = Application.Transpose(Range("$P$1:$P$12").Value) 'Values stored in "P1:P12"
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        If UBound(Filter(Arr, Target.Value)) > -1 Then
            Target.EntireRow.Validation.Delete
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @ O.PAL Thanks bro its working. Now I want to use Target.Value as dynamic range as I have a drop down list in the Column G. Could it possible to use it will multiple keywords instead of single. or dynamically get work from specified list. Thanks again